# create as many nodes when using user reference

Tags: nodes, rules, users

I have a User Reference field in one of my content type. When a user saves that content type selecting the users (we can select any number of users), I want to create another content type. The second content type has to be created by triggering a rule and has to be created as if the users selected in the first have created it. and if 3 users are selected 3 nodes of that type have to be created. how can we do this in drupal?

Comment: Is this being implemented on D6 or D7?

Comment: being implemented in D6